# In Azure Devops Release Pipeline, how can I get the name of the build associated with the release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have a release pipeline in Azure Devops. In the release pipeline I have a bash script -step that references the variable *$(Release.Artifacts.MyCustomAlias.BuildNumber)*. In the script I echo the value of the variable.

Now I created a new release and selected the build *20200820.22* as the artifact.

[image]

When checking the output of the script it is using the value *20200821.2*, which is the latest build, but not the one I selected.

How can I access the correct build version from the release script?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case.

[image]

And for this script:

```bsh
Write-Host $(Build.BuildNumber)

Write-Host $(Release.Artifacts.CustomName.BuildNumber)
```

I got correct result:

[image]

And since the newest build is `20200821.1` it picks up correct number. Please try `$(Build.BuildNumber)` which works for main artifact.

[image]